# How can I delete a folder using CMD utitilty in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a folder without any file in it in my external hard. I am able to rename it, but not able to delete it. I ran CMD utility as an administrator and I tried the commands "del foldername", "rd foldername", "deltree foldername" (the last one was not allowed in Windows XP). They give me the message "Access is denied." for "rd foldername". How can I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not cmd guru, but simple as 1-2-3 is delete folder using system account.

```
at 11:11pm /interactive cmd
```

Now if system command appear, delete folder:

```
del foldername
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
attrib /s foldername
```

This should show you the directory attributes.

If the response is

```
R   x:\dirname
```

then the directory is "read-only". In that case, execute

```
attrib -r foldername
```

and you should then be able to `rd` it.

It may be that the directory has (possibly hidden, possibly read-only) contents. The `attrib /s` should show these to you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried attrib foldername, and it showed SHR x:\dirname. I also tried attrib foldername -s -h, but it showed "Access is denied" again. I also tried attrib /s foldername, but it respond to me "File not found". What should I do now?

Comment: This is a read only hidden system file and I tried "attrib -r -h -s foldername" and "attrib -h -s foldername", but they didn't work. It shows "Access is denied."

Comment: You dont have permissions. Thats all. No matter if folder is read only or not.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but what's the reason and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Simple answer: Malware.